# Unable to download the file using fabric

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu-14.04, fabric

I am trying to download a file using Fabric's get() function, but unfortunately cannot. I have two VMs with username 'A' and 'B'.

Fabric showed this error; **'invalid user: A'** when I tried to download a file from Machine B to Machine A. So, I created a user A on both machines and granted them all privileges by adding in the 'visudo' file with `**A** ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL.

But still fabric is showing giving the permission denied error. I am unable to understand WHY?

```
get(remote_command, local_command, use_sudo=True)
```

Comment: Sorry! i didn't get your point

Comment: Please go ahead and post the actual code you are using that isn’t working.  The description that you provided isn’t enough.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the solution :). Actually, I was trying to download file from /opt/ directory to /opt/, which has the root privileges. Due to sudo_True I was able to download from /opt but couldn't keep file in /opt directory of my VM. So, I changed my approach by downloading the file on my home folder and then moving that into /opt/ directory.

Hope it helps :).